# How can I change Bootstrap CSS file in ASP.NET?

Tags: css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

Is possible to change between 2 CSS files?

For example: I have the default Bootstrap theme, but I want to make a dropdown list with a list of themes, so the user can select the theme that he wants. Searching I find that you can have something like that:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../Content/bootstrap.min.css" title="default"/>
<link type="text/css" rel="alternate stylesheet" href="../Content/bootstrap.min.cosmo.css" title="cosmos"/>
```

And you can change with a JavaScript function:

```
<script>
    function setActiveStyleSheet(title) {
        var i, a, main;
        for (i = 0; (a = document.getElementsByTagName("link")[i]) ; i++) {
            alert(a.href);
            if(a.getAttribute("rel").indexOf("style") != -1
               && a.getAttribute("title")) {
                a.disabled = true;
                if(a.getAttribute("title") == title) a.disabled = false;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

But when I click a button, I think that the page refresh and returns to the default theme.
Is there any way to permanently change the theme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can! You must get the url of the css file and add it to the BundleConfig and refresh the page. If you need some reference to workout with it take a look of this [link](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification)

Answer (score 0):

You need to persist which is the active stylesheet on client side. Probably via cookies.

Comment: Can you give me some example? Thanks!